# Ambiguous column name SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, ambiguous

I get the following error when I want to execute a SQL query:
"Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Ambiguous column name 'i_id'."

This is the SQL query I want to execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
FROM items x LEFT JOIN items y
ON y.i_id = x.i_id
AND x.last_seen < y.last_seen
WHERE x.last_seen > '4-4-2017 10:54:11' 
AND x.spot = 'spot773' 
AND (x.technology = 'Bluetooth LE' OR x.technology = 'EPC Gen2') 
AND y.id IS NULL
GROUP BY i_id
```

This is how my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[items] (
[id]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[i_id]       VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[last_seen]  DATETIME2 (0) NOT NULL,
[location]   VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
[code_hex]   VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[technology] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[url]        VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[spot]       VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC));
```

I've tried a couple of things but I'm not an SQL expert:)
Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

I do get duplicate rows when I remove the GROUP BY line as you can see:
[image]

Comment: You need to specify the table in your group by. "GROUP BY x.i_id"

Comment: You're missing the alias in the group by

Comment: `GROUP BY PUT_X_OR_Y_HERE.i_id` - This happens because there is an i_id in x and y and the server does not know which one you want to group by.

Comment: When I use GROUP BY x.i_id then I get the following error: " Column 'items.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. "

Comment: That is because you have to group by all columns that are not part of an aggregate. Perhaps remove the group by entirely?

Comment: What do you want those groups to *contain* in the result set?

Comment: If I don't use the GROUP BY then I get duplicate rows returned and I don't want that

Comment: You have DISTINCT in your query already which removes duplicates. Using distinct and group by in the same query is redundant.

Comment: your query has DISTINCT and GROUP BY. The distinct should be enough to eliminate duplicates

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` shouldn't return duplicate rows.  Are you sure the rows returned are duplicates?  The `GROUP BY` should be removed.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your post and provide sample data and expected result

Comment: I would also suggest using better aliases than x, y, z. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Those "duplicate" rows are not duplicates.  The first `id` column has different values.

Comment: Don't use select *. Select only the columns you actually need returned and your distinct will work because it would remove the "id" column which you are likely not using.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange !
I think it worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer in order to show how you'd typically select the lastest record per group without getting duplicates. You's use `ROW_NUMBER` for this, marking every last record per i_id with row number 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    i.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY i_id ORDER BY last_seen DESC) as rn
  FROM items i 
  WHERE last_seen > '2017-04-04 10:54:11' 
  AND spot = 'spot773' 
  AND technology IN ('Bluetooth LE', 'EPC Gen2') 
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

(You'd use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` if you wanted duplicates.)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the table alias in `GROUP BY i_id`.

Anyway, why are you writing an anti join query where you are trying to get rid of duplicates with both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`? Did you have issues with a straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` query? You are making things way more complicated than they actually are.

```
SELECT *
FROM items i 
WHERE last_seen > '2017-04-04 10:54:11' 
AND spot = 'spot773' 
AND technology IN ('Bluetooth LE', 'EPC Gen2') 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM items other
  WHERE i.i_id = other.i_id
    AND i.last_seen < other.last_seen
);
```

(There are other techniques of course to get the last seen record per `i_id`. This is one; another is to compare with `MAX(last_seen)`; another is to use `ROW_NUMBER`.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I am still getting duplicate rows? 
(see the picture in my post)

Comment: The rows you have highlighted in your picture **aren't duplicates**; they have different IDs. So you must define what you call a duplicate. You can then decide only to select the columns in question (i_id, last_seen, location, ...) withouth the ID and use `DISTINCT`. Or you decide to show one of the IDs (e.g. the maximum one). You'd select the columns plus `max(id)` then and group by all columns except for the ID.